# Nested queries in SQL from hr.employees

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a task like this:
Using the HR.EMPLOYEES table, build a list of employees whose work experience in the company is below the average.

I tried to do this, but an error occurs, how can I rewrite the request correctly?

```
select first_name, last_name from hr.empolyees 
where MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, hire_date) < (select avg(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, hire_date) from hr.employees)
```

Comment: and what error do you have?

Comment: unexpected end of SQL command

Comment: One issue I can see is that the first `hr.empolyees` is spelled incorrectly - it should be `hr.employees`.

Comment: looks like the avg function is missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like the `AVG` function is missing a closing parenthesis.

```
SELECT first_name, 
       last_name 
FROM hr.empolyees 
WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, hire_date) < (SELECT AVG(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, hire_date)) FROM hr.employees)
```